# Compute adjacency matrix from shortest distance matrix

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a way to compute an adjacency matrix from a given shortest distance matrix?

I have a set of graph vertices and would like to generate a graph (add edges), which reflects given shortest distances.

I'd appreciate pointers for getting started, if the problem is even solvable.

Comment: Interesting problem. Don't have much to suggest, but does this look useful : https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6588 - "Graph Reconstruction via Distance Oracles".